# Nextcord: sending a message from a .txt

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

I want to send a random line from a `.txt` from my discord bot, I am using `nextcord` but if `discord.py` works better I can use that to. Let me know if anyone can help.

I haven't tried much as I am fairly new to python but thought I would give it a try. I tried using random and `.json` but it went horribly lol.

Comment: Could you plz add your actual code, even if it went horribly ? if you're new to python, it's possible you're missing some basics. It's easier for us to debug a code we can copy/paste, and figure out where you're in trouble.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how nextcord works but there is a way you can get a random line from a `.txt` file in any python file.

Firstly, make sure your `.txt` file is in the same folder as your python file. Secondly we should import random as we will use `random.choice` in this method. Then, you can create a function which chooses a random line from a text file which looks like this:

```
def random_line(fname):
    lines = open(fname).read().splitlines()
    return random.choice(lines)
```

We can just call this function whenever we want to get a random line from a `.txt` file.

Now that we have a way to get a random line from a `.txt` file, we can implement this into `discord.py`.This is how you would create this command in `discord.py`

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

FILE_NAME = ""
YOUR_TOKEN = ""
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">", intents=intents)

#The function that gets the random line
def random_line(fname):
    lines = open(fname).read().splitlines()
    return random.choice(lines)

#Making the comand
@bot.command()
async def randomline(ctx):
    await ctx.send(random_line(FILE_NAME))

bot.run(YOUR_TOKEN)
```

And remember to enable intents  in the [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

If you would like to use `nextcord` just try to use the function that I gave you to make this command. I hope this helps and if there were any problems just let me kow.

Comment: No problem, remember to mark this as the answer since it is working (: